# Como fazer explode dentro do array de $request->all()

Tags: php, array, laravel

Preciso percorrer este array e pegar todas as chaves que começem com col. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

```
array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "NZ68b8h3L560aUc6DXBeb8Myb4JFD0hSgfSpJ2Lk"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "col1-22" => "22"
  "col1-26" => "26"
  "col2-23" => "23"
  "col2-24" => "24"
  "col3-24" => "24"
  "col3-25" => "25"
]
```

Comment: Você gostaria de fazer o explode com qual delimitador?

Comment: Poderia coloca na pergunta? Eu não consigo colar.

Comment: o delimitador é o hífen "-".

Comment: Qual a finalidade do `explode()`?

Comment: Por que explodir o valor no hífen se o valor relacionado àquela chave já é o valor desejado? Por exemplo, não precisa fazer `explode("-", "col1-22")` para obter o 22 se basta acessar a posição `"col1-22"` do *array*.

Comment: @StenioFrancis olha a lógica `col1-22" => "22"
  "col1-26" => "26"
  "col2-23" => "23"
  "col2-24" => "24"
  "col3-24" => "24"
  "col3-25" => "25"` Todos são parecidos `col`.

Comment: sim, vamos esquecer o explode, como eu percorro o array e pego as chaves a partir do col?

Comment: @StenioFrancia você quer o nome da key ou value das cols?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a função [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) para encontrar a posição da primeira ocorrência de uma string.

Como a função retorna a posição numérica da primeira ocorrência e você quer as chaves que iniciam com a string `col`, então o retorno da função deve ser igual a `0`. Desta forma, chaves como `_column` não serão incluídas - observação feita por *@AndersonCarlosWoss*.

```
$cols = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'col') === 0) {
        $cols[] = $key;
    }
}

print_r($cols); //Array ( [0] => col1-22 [1] => col1-26 [2] => col2-23 [3] => col2-24 [4] => col3-24 [5] => col3-25 )
```

> Caso haja chaves que iniciem com "*col*", como por exemplo "*column*", estas também serão incluídas no array `$cols`.

Comment: Eu não recomendaria deixar `> -1` pois isso buscará pelo termo em toda a *string*; ou seja, se houvesse uma chave `"_column"` ela também seria retornada, mesmo sem começar com "col"

Comment: @VictorCarnaval `if (strpos($key, 'col') !== false strpos($key,'col') == 2) {
        $cols[] = $key; 
    }` O tamanho de col é 3,então está na index 2.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, obrigado pela observação, vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper Isso não funcionará neste caso por causa da comparação frouxa. Seria necessário fazer `!== false`, ou como o Victor colocou, `> -1`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu iam colocar,eu até editei.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper Continua errado.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Porque esqueci do `&&`? `if (strpos($key, 'col') !== false && strpos($key,'col') === 0) { $cols[] = $key; }`

Comment: @MauryDeveloper Porque a função `strpos` retorna o índice onde inicia a *string*, não onde termina. Não faz diferença o tamanho da *string* que está buscando, o índice desejado será 0 já que queremos apenas as que iniciam com esse valor. Pode ler mais sobre a função na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Eu sei,mas esqueci . Obrigado por avisa.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um `foreach` e pegar a chave e partir daí fazer o `explode`

```
<?php 
    $array = array(
              "_token" => "NZ68b8h3L560aUc6DXBeb8Myb4JFD0hSgfSpJ2Lk",
              "_method" => "PUT",
              "col1-22" => "22",
              "col1-26" => "26",
              "col2-23" => "23",
              "col2-24" => "24",
              "col3-24" => "24",
              "col3-25" => "25"
             );

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $result = substr($key, 0, 3);
        if( $result == 'col' ){
            $exp = explode('-', $key);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($exp);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    }        
?>
```

Espqero que ajude

Comment: Você poderia coloca qual index está o `-`. strpos

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução com  recurso a collection  do Laravel

```
$array = array(
            "_token" => "NZ68b8h3L560aUc6DXBeb8Myb4JFD0hSgfSpJ2Lk",
            "_method" => "PUT",
            "col1-22" => "22",
            "col1-26" => "26",
            "col2-23" => "23",
            "col2-24" => "24",
            "col3-24" => "24",
            "col3-25" => "25"
           );

        $keys=collect($array)->filter(function ($value, $key) {
            return Str::startsWith($key, 'col'); }
        )->keys();
```